# Is $f$ integrable under this conditions?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Lebesgue measure and let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Assume that
>   $$\iint f(x,y) dx dy < \infty$$
>   Is $f$ integrable? Suppose $f$ is integrable, is then true that
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f = \iint f(x,y)dx dy\, ?$$

I know that if the on $[0,1]^2$ the answer for the first question is negative considering 
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
since both iterates are finite but 
$$\iint \left | \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right | dx dy = \infty$$
and hence it is not integrable. But I'm not sure if this works for $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead.

For the second question, I believe it is true by Fubini's theorem but I'd like to be sure. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Throw in the indicator function of $[0,1]^2$

Comment: @Cauchy Oh, right! Can you post your comment as an answer so the question won't appear as unanswered please? And thank you very much!